# After adding Feature Name and Feature Value query takes more than 5 minutes

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, database-performance, stuff

I work on SQL Server 2014 and my issue occurred after displaying Feature Name and Feature Value separated by $.

When executing the query below after adding Feature Name and Feature Value with `stuff` it became very slow.

How to enhance it?

Before adding the two `stuff` statements it took 28 seconds to display 750 thousand records. Now as below script and after adding two `stuff` statements take 5 minutes.

Script below give me expected result but issue is performance is very slow.

So can I do separate Feature Name and Feature Value to make it faster? Separated by $ if possible.

My script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[gen]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[gen]    

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[PartAttributes]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[PartAttributes]    

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.core_datadefinition_Detailes') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE core_datadefinition_Detailes
    
CREATE TABLE core_datadefinition_Detailes
(
     [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
     [ColumnName] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
     [ColumnNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
        
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Core_DataDefinition_Details] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)

INSERT INTO core_datadefinition_Detailes([ColumnNumber],[ColumnName])
VALUES (202503, 'Product Shape Type'),
       (1501170111, 'Type'),
       (202504, 'Package Family')
    
    
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[gen]
(
     [TradeCodeControlID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [CodeTypeID] [int] NULL,
     [RevisionID] [bigint] NULL,
     [Code] [varchar](20) NULL,
     [ZPLID] [int] NULL,
     [ZfeatureKey] [bigint] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[gen] ON 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[gen] ([TradeCodeControlID], [CodeTypeID],[RevisionID], [Code], [ZPLID], [ZfeatureKey]) 
VALUES (7565, 849774, 307683692, N'8541100050', 4239, 202503)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[gen] ([TradeCodeControlID], [CodeTypeID],[RevisionID], [Code], [ZPLID], [ZfeatureKey]) 
VALUES (7566, 849774, 307683692, N'8541100050', 4239, 202504)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[gen] ([TradeCodeControlID], [CodeTypeID],[RevisionID], [Code], [ZPLID], [ZfeatureKey]) 
VALUES (7567, 849774, 307683692, N'8541100050', 4239, 1501170111)
    
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[gen] OFF
    
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PartAttributes]
(
     [PartID] [int] NOT NULL,
     [ZfeatureKey] [bigint] NULL,
     [AcceptedValuesOption_Value] [float] NULL,
     [FeatureValue] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PartAttributes] ([PartID], [ZfeatureKey],  [FeatureValue]) 
VALUES (413989, 202503, N'Discrete')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PartAttributes] ([PartID], [ZfeatureKey],  [FeatureValue]) 
VALUES (413989, 1501170111, N'Zener')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PartAttributes] ([PartID], [ZfeatureKey],  [FeatureValue]) 
VALUES (413989, 202504, N'SOT')
    
SELECT  
    PartID, Code, Co.CodeTypeID, Co.RevisionID, Co.ZPLID,
    COUNT(1) AS ConCount,
    STUFF((SELECT '$' + CAST(CP.ColumnName AS VARCHAR(300)) AS [text()]
           FROM
               (SELECT DISTINCT
                    d.ColumnName, C.codeTypeId, C.Code, C.ZfeatureKey 
                FROM gen C 
                INNER JOIN core_datadefinitiondetails d WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.ZfeatureKey = d.columnnumber
                INNER JOIN PartAttributes P ON P.partid = PM.partid) CP
           WHERE CP.codeTypeId = Co.codeTypeId AND CP.Code = Co.Code
           ORDER BY CP.ZfeatureKey
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,  1, '') AS FeatureName,
    STUFF((SELECT '$' + CAST(CP2.FeatureValue AS VARCHAR(300)) AS [text()]
           FROM
               (SELECT DISTINCT
                    P.FeatureValue, C2.codeTypeId, C2.Code, C2.ZfeatureKey 
                FROM gen C2
                INNER JOIN PartAttributes P ON C2.ZfeatureKey = P.ZfeatureKey) CP2
           WHERE CP2.codeTypeId = Co.codeTypeId AND CP2.Code = Co.Code
           ORDER BY CP2.ZfeatureKey
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,  1, '') AS FeatureValue
FROM 
    PartAttributes PM 
INNER JOIN    
    gen Co ON Co.ZfeatureKey = PM.ZfeatureKey
GROUP BY
    PartID, Code, Co.CodeTypeID, Co.RevisionID, Co.ZPLID
```

Final result:

[final result after add two stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2JFO.png)

Comment: For performance related questions please provide the execution plan using "Paste The Plan".

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkXSLJQKt

Comment: Any chance you can remove `distinct` from `SELECT distinct d.ColumnName` and `SELECT distinct P.FeatureValue`?

Comment: why remove distinct i put distinct to remove duplicate also because i can't order by feature key